# How do ISPs block sites?

Tags: http, redirect, https, tcp

So I am interested in how ISPs block sites. I know that some achieve it with DNS, or by sending a fake 301 redirect(when connecting to an insecure site(HTTP)), which leads to their own page that says the site is blocked, when using HTTPS they could simply send fake RSTs... But how else do ISPs block sites? Is it possible for an ISP to send something like a fake 301 redirect over HTTPS?(I mean it's possible over HTTP since the payload is not encrypted,but is it achievable over HTTPS?) How would they do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic here since it is not related to programming. A better site to ask such questions would probably be [security.se].

Comment: Here you go https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64568/how-does-a-country-block-censor-an-encrypted-website-https/